# Cassandra dropped mutations

Tags: cassandra

```
7/15/17
5:13:49.602 PM  
{"line":"*|1|INFO|m2mmc_bm_platform_c1_cassandra_cassandra5.ef78f1ec-665a-11e7-8113-0242432187ce|110|m2mmc|cassandra|cassandra|m2mmc/bm/platform/c1/cassandra|org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService:1048|2017/07/15 17:13:49.602|MUTATION messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 174 for internal timeout and 0 for cross node timeout. Mean internal dropped latency: 2395 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 0 ms","source":"stdout","tag":"f8a31682d73b"}
Show syntax highlighted
```

I got the above error for one of my nodes .Is this  really a problem? Since we run repairs every week the data should be consistent eventually.

I did not see any GC in system.log at that time.

Answer (score 3):

Dropped mutations aren't typically a problem, as long as they're not occurring regularly. Your 2.3s latency suggests a GC pause, disk hang, or some other problem, but if it only happened this one time, repair/read repair will fix it, and you don't have anything to worry about. If it keeps happening, you should identify the cause.